# what is the difference between delay and Thread.sleep in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to figure out or to prove "how a delay is suspending function".
So, I wrote an example here

```
var time: Long? = null
    var job1 = GlobalScope.launch() {
        println("Coroutine ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        time = measureTimeMillis {
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            println("After 1 seconds")
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            println("After 1 seconds")
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            println("After 1 seconds")
        }

    }
    println("Thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")

    runBlocking {
        job1.join()
        println("Proccesed time is $time")
    }
```

the Output I got is

```
Thread main
Coroutine DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
After 1 seconds
After 1 seconds
After 1 seconds
Proccesed time is 3015
```

Then i replaced `Thread.sleep` with `delay` and still the processed time is `3045 ms`.

I don't find any difference between `Thread.sleep` with `delay`.
How to prove that it is a `Suspending Function` and is different from `Thread.sleep`

Comment: `delay` is a `suspend fun`, and it won't block the thread, while a call to `Thread.Sleep` will block the thread.

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă I Think that was there in document. But they didn't proved it.

Comment: `Thread.sleep` is a blocking function and should not be used in a coroutine. The point of coroutines is that the can 'pause' while others are executed on the SAME thread.

Comment: @al3c Ok, I got the point. But how to prove it in programming. Give me an example to show it is different. I read the documentation So many times and I know the concept well.

Answer (score 17):

### Delay is non-blocking

The main difference is that [`delay`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65333188/is-thread-sleep-different-with-virtual-threads-fibers-in-project-loom-for-ja) is a suspend function that won't block the thread, while `Thread.sleep()` blocks the thread (except when using Loom of course, [but that's another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65333188/is-thread-sleep-different-with-virtual-threads-fibers-in-project-loom-for-ja)).

In other words, `delay` means that the coroutine suspends for that amount of time, which in turn means that the underlying `Thread` is free to go service a different coroutine which delays and suspends, and so on for all coroutines.

With `Thread.sleep` on the other hand, the underlying Thread cannot jump from coroutine to coroutine -- rather each `Thread` is blocked until all the sleeps in the coroutine are over before it can go service the execution of another coroutine.

To prove this to yourself with code, run the code below, which starts  `coroutineCount` number of coroutines, each of which prints "1", delays, then prints "2", then delays again, then prints "3". Then does the same thing with `sleep`.

Change `coroutineCount` to 100 and then 200. The `Thread.sleep()` version will take longer and longer to execute because only the number of threads available in the default dispatcher thread pool (probably the number of processors on your machine minus one) can run each coroutine simultaneously. This is thread starvation.

On the other hand, the `delay` version will execute in just over 3 seconds, because there are no calls blocking the coroutine threads, and the limited number of threads in the dispatcher can service all of the coroutines concurrently.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlin.time.measureTime

suspend fun main() {
  val coroutineCount = 50
  val delayTime = 1_000L

  suspend fun delayDelayDelay() {
    delay(delayTime)
    print("1")
    delay(delayTime)
    print("2")
    delay(delayTime)
    print("3")
  }

  // not a suspend function, sleep is not a suspending call,
  // so suspend is redundant here
  fun sleepSleepSleep() {
    Thread.sleep(delayTime)
    print("1")
    Thread.sleep(delayTime)
    print("2")
    Thread.sleep(delayTime)
    print("3")
  }

  val timeDelay = measureTime {
    coroutineScope {
      // launch `coroutineCount` number of coroutines
      repeat(coroutineCount) {
        launch {
          // The default dispatcher has a limited number of threads (probably
          // number of processors - 1), but the delay version does not block
          // these threads, so all the coroutines will delay simultaneously,
          // and all the coroutines will print "1" simultaneously, so you'll
          // see `coroutineCount` number of "1"s all at once, a wait, and then
          // a bunch of "2"s, and then a bunch of "3"s.
          //
          // This will take just a bit longer than 3 * `delayTime`.
          delayDelayDelay()
        }
      }
    }
  }
  println("")
  println("Took $timeDelay to run $coroutineCount coroutines with delays")

  val timeThreads = measureTime {
    coroutineScope {
      // launch `coroutineCount` number of coroutines
      repeat(coroutineCount) {
        launch {
          // The sleep version uses the same dispatcher and limited number
          // of threads, but since sleep blocks / consumes the thread,
          // only the limited number of threads will run simultaneously.
          // Therefore you'll see a few "1"s, then nothing until those threads
          // are free, then a few "2"s, then nothing until those threads are
          // free, then a few "3"s. Then back to "1"s and so on until all the
          // coroutines are done.
          //
          // This will take much longer than 3 * `delayTime` as long as
          // `coroutineCount` is greater than the number of threads in the
          // default dispatcher. If `coroutineCount` is less than the number
          // of threads in the default dispatcher, it will have the same
          // behavior as the delay version.
          sleepSleepSleep()
        }
      }
    }
  }
  println("")
  println("Took $timeThreads to run $coroutineCount coroutines with sleeps")
}
```

When coroutine code runs as it should -- without blocking calls like `Thread.sleep()` -- threads are always available to service coroutines that need to execute. If there is no suspending equivalent available to a blocking call (for example, a 3rd party library that does synchronous I/O) , always encapsulate those calls within a dispatcher designed to run such blocking calls e.g. `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }`, leaving the other coroutine dispatchers free to service non-blocking coroutines.

If you make `sleepSleepSleep()` a `suspend` function, IntelliJ will actually warn you that `sleep` is a blocking call that can possibly lead to thread starvation.

### Multiplatform

A secondary difference is that `delay` is a [multiplatform](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform.html) call -- in other words, it is available on every platform that Kotlin supports (native, including iOS, JavaScript, WASM, JVM). Calls to `delay` can therefore be in common code.

The `Thread.sleep()` call is specific to the JVM, so calls to it can only be in code that targets the JVM, or environments such as Android that provide JVM compatibility.

Comment: @naanu No, that's not what I mean. `delay` works like `sleep` in that it does wait that amount of time before continuing. It just doesn't use up a Thread doing so. You indicated in a comment to your question you understood the concept well, so I'm not sure what the knowledge gap is. Nevertheless, I tried to add some additional explanatory text in my answer.

Comment: @naanu If you run the code with 100 coroutines, you will see the total time taken to execute is still just over 3 seconds, as expected with 3 delays of 1000ms. Doesn't that prove to you the `delay` is doing what it should be doing?

Comment: The way it "comes back" is via a continuation, which is essentially a callback under the hood. The Kotlin compiler creates the code necessary to "continue" the coroutine at the point where it suspended. See https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md#coroutines-overview for more information on this. The Thread on which it is continued is dependent on the dispatcher chosen, but generally can be any Thread available in the dispatcher.

Comment: In my experience `Thread.sleep()` usually sleeps the correct amount within a margin of O(3ms) whereas `delay()` is generally off by O(15ms) so occasionally there's a use for `Thread.sleep()` even in coroutine code if you need to sleep for a predictable and precise amount of time.

Comment: @Jonn a) that's not something your code should be relying on -- its likely dependent on your OS/CPU, scheduling, the JVM, etc. See https://web.archive.org/web/20160308031939/https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks, and b) `delay` uses `System.nanoTime` under the hood (on the JVM) so if you can reproduce O(15ms) differences consistently, you might have found a bug and should probably raise an issue. I tried to reproduce (https://gist.github.com/rocketraman/e24c5f312538d002f77a84bea7a3c4dd) and consistently got a resolution within a few hundred microseconds.

Answer (score 7):

I only will try to answer in a very simple way.

```
fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {

    launch {
        Thread.sleep(3000L)
     // delay(3000L)
        println("Coroutine 1 ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }

    launch {
        println("Coroutine 2 ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }
}
```

> ### Using Thread.sleep

- Here I have used `runBlocking` to wrap the execution of the main function. Which allows me to use `launch` keyword directly as it runs on context of `runBlocking`.
- both the `launch` coroutine will run on the `main` Thread. Which can be seen by printing the thread name.
- When `Thread.sleep(3000L)` is put inside first launch. The output is

```
Coroutine 1 main
Coroutine 2 main
```

*This is because, when first coroutine is executed it will come at Thread.sleep(3000L) which in turns block the main thread. So, main thread is blocked and it will not handle other threads for 3 seconds.*

*Then after 3 seconds `Coroutine 1 main` will get printed. and then `Coroutine 2 main` will be printed*

> ### Using delay

- now replace `Thread.sleep(3000L)` by `delay(3000L)`
- now when first coroutine is executed it will come at delay(3000L) which suspends the main thread.
- now main Thread will not wait for 3 seconds instead it will start executing other coroutines.
- Hence, it will execute coroutine 2 and prints `Coroutine 2 main` first.
- on back end after the delay of 3 second is over by coroutine 1. Then main Thread go back to Coroutine 1 and prints `Coroutine 1 main`
- So, output will be

```
Coroutine 2 main
Coroutine 1 main
```

Hence, we can prove that `Thread.sleep` will blocking the thread, whereas `delay` is just suspending the thread.

Comment: bases on "https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#scope-builder-and-concurrency you" are wrong dud, which is what now?

Answer (score 5):

Suspending a thread means that thread will "wait" doing something else in the meantime if necessary.
Blocking a thread means that thread will wait doing nothing no matter what.

You can prove that with this code:

```
fun log(message: String) {
    println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] : $message")
}

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val myThread = newSingleThreadContext("My Thread")

        launch(myThread) {
            (1..3).forEach {
                log("1st launch: $it")
                //delay(1000)
                Thread.sleep(1000)
            }
        }

        launch(myThread) {
            (1..3).forEach {
                log("2nd launch: $it")
                //delay(1000)
                Thread.sleep(1000)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output with `delay`:

```
[My Thread] : 1st launch: 1
[My Thread] : 2nd launch: 1
[My Thread] : 1st launch: 2
[My Thread] : 2nd launch: 2
[My Thread] : 1st launch: 3
[My Thread] : 2nd launch: 3
```

Output with `Thread.sleep`:

```
[My Thread] : 1st launch: 1
[My Thread] : 1st launch: 2
[My Thread] : 1st launch: 3
[My Thread] : 2nd launch: 1
[My Thread] : 2nd launch: 2
[My Thread] : 2nd launch: 3
```

Since `delay` is a suspending function it can be called only from inside a coroutine or from another suspending function.

Comment: @naanu. During `delay(1000)` the thread can be used to do other tasks (if there is other task scheduled for that thread) while those 1000 milliseconds pass. After 1000 milliseconds the thread will be resumed at the exact same point where it was suspended. I wouldn't say it will wait exactly 1000 milliseconds because the other task might "monopolize" the thread and it may take longer than that. With `Thread.sleep(1000)` the thread won't do anything but waiting for 1000 milliseconds to continue, that's why `Thread.sleep` is a blocking call.